# Get timing information from MFCC generated with librosa.feature.mfcc

Tags: python, audio, librosa, mfcc

I am extracting MFCCs from an audio file using Librosa's function (librosa.feature.mfcc) and I correctly get back a numpy array with the shape I was expecting: 13 MFCCs values for the entire length of the audio file which is 1292 windows (in 30 seconds).

What is missing is timing information for each window: for example I want to know what the MFCC looks like at time 5000ms, then at 5200ms etc.
Do I have to manually calculate the time? Is there a way to automatically get the exact time for each window?

[image: :]

Comment: You have to calculate it yourself.

Comment: OK, thanks.. I suspected it :(

Comment: It's very simple, I can drop you an example if you'd like one.

Comment: Well, if you don't mind dropping it...:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "timing information" is not directly available, as it depends on sampling rate. In order to provide such information, `librosa` would have create its own classes. This would rather pollute the interface and make it much less interoperable. In the current implementation, `feature.mfcc` returns you `numpy.ndarray`, meaning you can easily integrate this code anywhere in Python.

To relate MFCC to timing:

```
import librosa
import numpy as np

filename = librosa.util.example_audio_file()
y, sr = librosa.load(filename)

hop_length = 512 # number of samples between successive frames
mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, n_mfcc=13, sr=sr, hop_length=hop_length)

audio_length = len(y) / sr # in seconds
step = hop_length / sr # in seconds
intervals_s = np.arange(start=0, stop=audio_length, step=step)

print(f'MFCC shape: {mfcc.shape}')
print(f'intervals_s shape: {intervals_s.shape}')
print(f'First 5 intervals: {intervals_s[:5]} second')
```

Note that array length of `mfcc` and `intervals_s` is the same - a sanity check that we did not make a mistake in our calculation.

```
MFCC shape: (13, 2647) 
intervals_s shape: (2647,)
First 5 intervals: [0.         0.02321995 0.04643991 0.06965986 0.09287982] second
```